# Converting time in java with string manipulation

Tags: java

How can I convert `2m0s` to `00:02:00` in java? Both are string.

I tried string and char manipulation but unsuccessful.

I did it in PHP with this function

But I need to convert to java.

```
    preg_match_all('/(\d+)([HMS])/', $sections[2], $parts, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $units = array('H' => 'hours', 'M' => 'minutes', 'S' => 'seconds');
    foreach($parts as $part)
    {
      $result[$units[$part[2]]] = $part[1];
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, then we can help you fix the problems with your code.

Comment: So whats your problem with the Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this with regex, but a more fool proof solution would be to utilise the language's date API.

For Java that would mean using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String input = "2m0s";
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm'm'ss's'");
Date date = parseFormat.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
String output = displayFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(input + " -> " + output);
```

which will print: `2m0s -> 02:00` to your console. The nice thing is that input like `"2m75s"` would be converted to `"03:15"`.

More information on how to construct a pattern to parse strings, or format dates, can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't roll your own. The Joda-Time library can parse and generate those strings. The ISO 8601 standard defines that format. See the Wikipedia page for ISO 8601, look for the Durations section.